# extract the remaining time period

Tags: r

I have two data frames.

```
df1

             Tstart                Tend       start_temp
2012-12-19 21:12:00 2012-12-20 02:48:00 17.7637930350627
2013-01-31 17:36:00 2013-01-31 22:54:00 18.9618654078963
2013-02-14 09:12:00 2013-02-14 09:48:00 18.2361739981826
2013-02-21 15:36:00 2013-02-21 16:36:00 20.9938186870285
2013-03-21 03:54:00 2013-03-21 05:18:00 16.7130008152092
2013-03-30 23:42:00 2013-03-31 02:30:00 15.3775459369926

df2
           datetime airtemp
2012-12-11 23:00:00   14.40
2012-12-11 23:06:00   14.22
2012-12-11 23:12:00   14.04
2012-12-11 23:18:00   13.86
2012-12-11 23:24:00   13.68
2012-12-11 23:30:00   13.50
......
2015-03-31 23:24:00   15.46
2015-03-31 23:30:00   15.90
2015-03-31 23:36:00   15.82
2015-03-31 23:42:00   15.74
```

I want to extract the remaining datetime from df2 (df2 is a time series) other than the periods between startT and endT in df1.
Can you please help me to do this?
Many thanks.

Comment: You could try `foverlaps` from the `data.table` package.

Answer (score 0):

With base R we can try the following (with the following `df1` & `df2`):

```
df1 <- read.csv(text='Tstart, Tend, start_temp
2012-12-19 21:12:00, 2012-12-20 02:48:00, 17.7637930350627
2013-01-31 17:36:00, 2013-01-31 22:54:00, 18.9618654078963
2013-02-14 09:12:00, 2013-02-14 09:48:00, 18.2361739981826
2013-02-21 15:36:00, 2013-02-21 16:36:00, 20.9938186870285
2013-03-21 03:54:00, 2013-03-21 05:18:00, 16.7130008152092
2013-03-30 23:42:00, 2013-03-31 02:30:00, 15.3775459369926', header=TRUE)

df2 <- read.csv(text='datetime, airtemp
2012-12-11 23:00:00,   14.40
2012-12-11 23:06:00,   14.22
2012-12-11 23:12:00,   14.04
2012-12-11 23:18:00,   13.86
2012-12-11 23:24:00,   13.68
2012-12-19 23:30:00,   13.50
2013-03-21 04:24:00,   15.46
2013-03-21 23:30:00,   15.90
2015-03-31 23:36:00,   15.82
2015-03-31 23:42:00,   15.74', header=TRUE)

df1$Tstart <- strptime(as.character(df1$Tstart), '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
df1$Tend <- strptime(as.character(df1$Tend), '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
df2$datetime <- strptime(as.character(df2$datetime), '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')

indices <- sapply(1:nrow(df2), function(j) all(sapply(1:nrow(df1), function(i) df2[j,]$datetime < df1[i,]$Tstart | df2[j,]$datetime > df1[i,]$Tend)))
df2[indices,]
#              datetime airtemp
#1  2012-12-11 23:00:00   14.40
#2  2012-12-11 23:06:00   14.22
#3  2012-12-11 23:12:00   14.04
#4  2012-12-11 23:18:00   13.86
#5  2012-12-11 23:24:00   13.68
#8  2013-03-21 23:30:00   15.90
#9  2015-03-31 23:36:00   15.82
#10 2015-03-31 23:42:00   15.74
```

Comment: Thank you very much. Unfortunately only for the code df2$datetime <- strptime(df2$datetime, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S') it gives the below error.    
Error in `[<-.data.table`(x, j = name, value = value) : 
  (list) object cannot be coerced to type 'double'
In addition: Warning message:
In `[<-.data.table`(x, j = name, value = value) :
  Supplied 11 items to be assigned to 2 items of column 'datetime' (9 unused)

Comment: I guess you have data.table, can you have dataframe instead? Updated the code adding the creation of the data frames, if you have your data in the same format, it should work. Try the above sample code first.